# Why is File Upload slow in IE when SSL being used?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, upload, file-upload

Boy do I have a strange bug. 
I have a website that needs to upload large files. 
We are using the standard ASPx FileUpload control. 
We have modified the web.config to allow really large files.

I am doing all these tests in FireFox, IE6, and IE7. 
For my test I am using a few 20 MB files (AVI, PDF, Excel). 
The file type does not affect the results. 
I can upload these files just fine in all browsers with about the same results. 
Each file takes between 30 and 40 seconds. 
If I turn on SSL on my website, the code still works, but the upload in IE takes 5 to 10 times as long. Everything works, it is just way slower.
I used file monitor, and it looks like IE is reading the file 3 times. FireFox reads it only one time. 
I also have noticed this slowness in IE occurs on PCs with Office 2003 or 2007 installed.

How often does IE wants to renegotiate the SSL keys? Can I change this? Why would FireFox be so fast? Most of my users have IE, so this is a real pain.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the test conditions when using IE, are you using a host name only and being considered an intranet user?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem occurs internal and external with IE. Nothing else is running other than the browser. The OS is XP Pro.

Comment: Are you using self-signed (untrusted) SSL cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do is fire up [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler) and observe the converstations between the server and the browsers to see if there is any difference in behaviour.

Caveat: Fiddler can actually actually change the way SSL works so it may not be fully trustworthy guide but it might give you clues as to where to look.

Comment: Fiddler helpped. Thanks. I can see that IE is making extra calls, and renegotiate the SSL keys more often that FireFox. What I do not get, it why IE works correctly of some systems that appear to have the same configuration. If I find an answer I will post it here.